# Find out number of available USB endpoints

Tags: linux, usb, embedded

I am running Linux on an embedded system. The [SoC](https://linux-sunxi.org/V3s) of the system has a USB 2.0 port, and the [datasheet](https://linux-sunxi.org/images/2/23/Allwinner_V3s_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf) claims that there are 8 endpoints available.

Is there any way I can verify this in software? Perhaps an entry somewhere in `/proc` or `/sys`? I can see the number of endpoints occupied by a USB device through `/sys/bus/usb/devices/**/bNumEndpoints`, but I wonder if it's possible to determine the total number of available endpoints on the system in software.

Answer (score 1):

Page 46 of {the datasheet you linked](https://linux-sunxi.org/images/2/23/Allwinner_V3s_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf) says:

> Up to 8 User-Configurable Endpoints in device mode

*"In device mode"* means when the SoC is acting as an USB device instead of a USB host. In Linux, this is called *USB Gadget mode*.

To configure USB gadget mode at run-time, you apparently need the kernel build option CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS, which requires CONFIGFS_FS. You would also need USB_LIBCOMPOSITE and one or more USB_G_* options according to what kind of functionality you'll want the SoC to present to the USB host it's connected to.

Configuring USB gadget functionality is described in [Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.rst](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.rst) in Linux kernel source documentation, and other gadget_*.rst files in the same directory document (some of) the gadget functionalities you can use. Each function will use one or more endpoints, and with this SoC, you only have 8 endpoints available.

For example, if you configure your SoC to present a single `ttyACM`-style serial channel, it takes three endpoints: one for the control interface, and two for data interface (one endpoint for transmit, another for receive).

Each endpoint is listed as an `E: ...` line in `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` if you have debugfs mounted, so

```
grep ^E: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | wc -l
```

will tell you how many endpoints your current USB gadget configuration uses.

If you don't trust the datasheet, I guess you could pick a combination of gadget functions that uses the number of endpoints specified in the datasheet, try configuring it while checking for any errors reported, then verify at the USB host side that all the endpoints for each configured function are accessible.

If you don't know how many endpoints your USB device/OTG controller chip claims to support in gadget mode, I guess you could run a loop to create USB gadget functions until you get an error, then check how many of the generated functions and endpoints the USB host system will be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

`lshw` would list your ports includung what standard they support.

Comment: I did not see `lshw` implemented in embedded systems quite often.